# Word to fit in the phrase "X with me,"

Tags: word-choice

It is sort of like "Bear with me for a second." It would mean to keep listening while an idea is explained, or accept a premise while the explanation is happening. I'm pretty sure it starts with a p, and it's sort of like "patronize" but with less implicit skepticism. Thanks!

Comment: That "p" for Peter got me thinking about the word 'appreciate" which has a strong 'pree' sound in its second syllable. Thus I'd like to propose the following: "I appreciate what you're saying. Please continue".

Comment: There is "humor me." Maybe in some places it's spelled with a silent "p", like in "ptarmigan"?

Comment: The question seems clear to me: what is a synonym for the phrase "bear with me."

Answer (score 0):

Indulge.

to patiently allow (someone) to do or say something (Merriam-Webster)

PS: You threw me off with that p. Placate crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

How about *be patient with*, which is another way to say *bear with me*?

From the Free Dictionary:

> [*bear with
>   someone/somebody*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+with): to
>   *be patient with* someone or something [emphasis added]

*Patient* begins with a "p", and unlike "patronize me", bears no implicit skepticism.

> "*Be patient with* me for a second" or "Please *be patient with* me for a
>   second."